# Another web server with SSL is already running

Tags: xampp, debian

when I start xampp, this error pompts out. However, my computer is just turn on and no apache in this dir /etc/init.d.
How shoule I check where the "Another web server" is and how to solve it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: try using `netstat -lpnt` and look for port 80

Answer (score 0):

You may have both Apache server and xampp running at the time. try shuting down apache server then start xampp

Comment: I meant to say "running at the SAME time"

Comment: you can edit your own answer and correct anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

you most find the process that uses port :443
`$sudo netstat -ltnp | grep :443`
then kill the process with PID
`$sudo kill PID`
then restart the apache with this command:
`$sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start`
keep developing...